# Get specific values from Xml

Tags: c#, xpath, xmldocument

I don't how to extract the values from XML document, and am looking for some help as I'm new to C#

I am using `XmlDocument` and then `XmlNodeList` for fetching the particular XML document

Here is my code

```
XmlNodeList XMLList = doc.SelectNodes("/response/result/doc");
```

And my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<result>
  <doc>
    <long name="LoadID">494</long>
    <long name="EventID">5557</long>
    <str name="XMLData"><TransactionDate>2014-05-28T14:17:31.2186777-06:00</TransactionDate><SubType>tblQM2222Components</SubType><IntegerValue title="ComponentID">11111</IntegerValue></str></doc>
  <doc>
    <long name="LoadID">774</long>
    <long name="EventID">5558</long>
    <str name="XMLData"><TransactionDate>2014-05-28T14:17:31.2186777-06:00</TransactionDate><SubType>tblQM2222Components</SubType><IntegerValue title="ComponentID">11111</IntegerValue></str></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

In this i have to fetch every the `XMLData` data that is under every `doc tag` and i have to fetch last doc tag `EventID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var docs = xml.Root.Elements("doc");

var lastDocEventID = docs.Last()
                         .Elements("long")
                         .First(l => (string)l.Attribute("name") == "EventID")
                         .Value;

Console.WriteLine ("Last doc EventId: " +lastDocEventID);

foreach (var doc in docs)
{
    Console.WriteLine (doc.Element("str").Element("TransactionDate").Value);
}
```

prints:

```
Last doc EventId: 5558
2014-05-28T14:17:31.2186777-06:00
2014-05-28T14:17:31.2186777-06:00
```

Comment: Thanks,for your valuable suggestion,but how to get the XMLDATA of each Doc Tag.can you please tell me the syntax like which you already given above

Answer (score 1):

You can use two XPath expressions to select the nodes you want. To answer each part of your question in turn:

To select all of the `XMLData` nodes:

```
XmlNodeList XMLList 
      = doc.SelectNodes("/response/result/doc/str[@name='XMLData']");
```

To select the last EventId:

```
XmlNode lastEventIdNode = 
   doc.SelectSingleNode("/response/result/doc[position() = 
                          last()]/long[@name='EventID']");
```

If not all doc nodes are guaranteed to have an event id child node, then you can simply:

```
XmlNodeList eventIdNodes = 
    doc.SelectNodes("/response/result/doc[long[@name='EventID']]");
XmlNode lastNode = eventIdNodes[eventIdNodes.Count - 1];
```

That should give you what you've asked for.

**Update;**

If you want the XML data inside each strXml element, you can use the [InnerXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innerxml.aspx) property:

```
XmlNodeList xmlList 
      = doc.SelectNodes("/response/result/doc/str[@name='XMLData']");
foreach(XmlNode xmlStrNode in xmlList)
{
    string xmlInner = xmlStrNode.InnerXml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one `result` tag short in your xml.

Try using this. It's cleaner too imho

```
XmlNodeList docs = doc.SelectSingleNode("response").SelectSingleNode("result").SelectNodes("doc");
```

Then you can use a combination of `SelectSingleNode`, `InnerText`, `Value` to get the data from each XmlNode in your list.

For example if you want the EventID from the first `doc` tag:

```
int eventID = int.Parse(docs[0].SelectSingleNode("long[@name='EventID']").InnerText);
```

Comment: Thanks,for your valuable suggestion,but how to get the EventID of each Doc Tag.can you please tell me the syntax like which you already given above

Comment: I edited my post to show a way to get the EventID from the first doc tag for example